# Isolate test lab from network, but still access internet?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I'm setting up a 2003 Server vm for testing purposes as a AD controller with DHCP.  It's connected to a network with a DSL router already serving DHCP addresses to numerous other client machines.

I've configured the server vm with 2 NICs.

One is connected to the 'real' network of the DSL router.  Server is 10.0.0.200 and the router is 10.0.0.2.
The other is connected to the virtual host only network, with an address of 192.168.1.2.  This will be the address I want to configure for the test lab to do AD, DNS etc.

How to I configure it, such that the physical machines on the 10.0.0.0 network never see my test server, yet the virtual clients on the 192.168.1.0 network can still access the internet through the DSL router at 10.0.0.2.  Keeping in mind I want the virtual clients to use the vm server as their DNS server.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off with implementing this as the firewall than with an internal machine as outlined. Look into rras, configure as a router and add some IP restrictions to block you main subnet. That should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a quick look into RRAS (I'm a raw newbie when it comes to this) it does indeed look like it may prove to be a simpler solution.  Out of interest, is my initial plan workable?  Are there any advantages of one approach over the other, or indeed which would be considered best practice in a production environment?